# Error in Fullcalendar with json and web2py

Tags: json, fullcalendar, web2py

I´m calling:

```
events: {
    url: '/CondominioVip/evento/evento_json.json',
    error: function() {
        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
    }
}
```

I've also tried to add `type: 'POST`  but it didn't work either.

My controller:

```
def evento_json():
    events= "[{'title':'event1','start':'2010-01-01'},{'title':'event3','start':'2010-01-09 12:30:00','allDay':False}]"
    return events
```

Test call from browser (`http://localhost:8000/CondominioVip/evento/evento_json.json`):

> [{'title':'event1','start':'2010-01-01'},{'title':'event3','start':'2010-01-09 12:30:00','allDay':False}]

Request from web2py ajax function:

> Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
>   Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
>   Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
>   Accept-Language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
>   Cache-Control:max-age=0
>   Connection:keep-alive
>   Content-Length:31
>   Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Cookie:session_id_admin=127.0.0.1-f9db7d99-4e7e-4bae-a229-d6614e9599f0; cvip_language=pt-BR; session_id_condominiovip=127.0.0.1-b820cbe3-9a55-40bb-8618-8d3f9a43f7c2
>   Host:`localhost:8000`
>   Origin:`http://localhost:8000`
>   Referer:`http://localhost:8000/CondominioVip/evento/index/2`
>   User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.46 Safari/536.5
>   X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Response headers:

> Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
>   Connection:keep-alive
>   Content-Length:105
>   Content-Type:application/json
>   Date:Tue, 29 May 2012 02:54:04 GMT
>   Expires:Tue, 29 May 2012 02:54:03 GMT
>   Pragma:no-cache
>   Server:Rocket 1.2.4 Python/2.7.3
>   Set-Cookie:cvip_language=pt-BR; expires=Wed, 30-May-2012 02:54:04 GMT; Path=/, session_id_condominiovip=127.0.0.1-b820cbe3-9a55-40bb-8618-8d3f9a43f7c2; Path=/
>   X-Powered-By:web2py

Response:

> [{'title':'event1','start':'2010-01-01'},{'title':'event3','start':'2010-01-09 12:30:00','allDay':False}]

I'm out of options. Any help would be apprecianted.

Update:

I've installed the JsonView extension on Chrome, so returning a string is not considered a json response.

I made some changes:

```
def evento_json():
    rows = db(evento.id>0).select(evento.id,evento.titulo,evento.data_hora_inicio,evento.data_hora_fim)
    events = []
    for row in rows:
        event = {'title': row['titulo'],
                 'start': row['data_hora_inicio'],
                 'end': row['data_hora_fim'],
                 'allDay': False,
                 'url': URL(c='evento', f='index', args=[row['id']], extension=False)}
        events.append(event)
    return events
```

But web2py throws an error. I´ve printed "events" and "json(events)" before send it to generic.json, and the format is exactly what fullcalendar expects.

The way I found to stop the error is:

In controller:

```
def evento_json():
    import datetime
    start = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(request.vars['start'])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    end = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(request.vars['end'])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    set = db((evento.id>0) &
             (evento.data_hora_inicio >= start) &
             (evento.data_hora_fim <= end))

    if (not auth.has_membership(auth.id_group(role='site_admin'), auth.user.id)) and \
       (not auth.has_membership(auth.id_group(role='cond_admin'), auth.user.id)):
        set = set(evento.flag_disp==True)

    rows = set.select(evento.id,
                      evento.titulo,
                      evento.data_hora_inicio,
                      evento.data_hora_fim,
                      evento.flag_disp)

    events = []
    for row in rows:
        event = {'title': row['titulo'],
                 'start': row['data_hora_inicio'],
                 'end': row['data_hora_fim'],
                 'allDay': False,
                 'url': URL(c='evento', f='index', args=[row['id']], extension=False),
                 'color': 'blue' if row['flag_disp'] is True else 'red'}
        events.append(event)

    if events:
        from gluon.serializers import json
        return XML(json(events))
    else:
        return '{}'
```

And create a view evento/evento_json.json with the following:

> {{=response._vars)}}

It works! But seems a bug to me. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
events= "[{'title':'event1','start':'2010-01-01'},{'title':'event3','start':'2010-01-09T12:30:00Z','allDay':false}]"
```

(Changed the event3 start date/time to ISO8601 format as per the [API](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/), and changed "False" to "false".)